# how to setState inside streambuilder

Tags: flutter, stream-builder, statefulwidget

I have a streamBuilder inside a stateful widget that gets data asynchronously from the server. Additionally, I have a list that collects those data.

```
StreamBuilder(   
  stream: myStream.stream,   
  initialData: initData,   
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch(snapshot.connectionState){
          case (Connection.active):
            setState(() { 
              data = data + snapshot.data;
            });
            break;
          default: 
            break;
        }   
      } 
)
```

If I do this, I get the `setState() or markNeedBuild() was called during build`.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: use for example `Stream.map()` method to concatenate stream data

Comment: @pskink isn't `stream.map()` for transforming incoming data? I'm trying to collect data.

Comment: @pskink I'm confused to what you mean by return the original `event`

Comment: stream.map((event) {foo += event; return event;})

Comment: @pskink hmm I think I get what you are saying, but isn't that a bit hacky? What's the best practice with this kind of tasks?

Comment: `Stream.transform` maybe? but i dont think it pays off in your case...

Comment: @pskink I guess I can forgo the streambuilder and use stream.listen on events instead.

Comment: btw check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html, it reads: *"Widget rebuilding is scheduled by each interaction, using State.setState, but is otherwise decoupled from the timing of the stream. The builder is called at the discretion of the Flutter pipeline, and will thus receive a timing-dependent sub-sequence of the snapshots that represent the interaction with the stream."*

Comment: @pskink setState inside stream listen doesn't trigger widget rebuild. So I guess I'll have to post a new question on that.

Comment: @pskink I got rid of `StreamBuilder` and used `stream.listen((event) {setState((){ data = data + event; }); }`, and I initialized it in `initState()` of my stateful Widget

Comment: @pskink that was my mistake. it works. Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Flutter [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) doesn't need to call setState to rebuild its children. StreamBuilder rebuilds by default when change were detected on stream. If no Widgets are needed to be rebuilt inside the StreamBuilder, you may consider initializing a Stream [listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) and append the new data when changes were detected on stream.